# What is the difference between CrossEntropy and NegativeLogLikelihood in MXNet?

Tags: python, classification, mxnet, loss-function, cross-entropy

I was trying to evaluate my classification models with log-loss metric using [mxnet.metric](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/_modules/mxnet/metric.html) module.

I came across two classes: [`CrossEntropy`](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/api/python/metric/metric.html#mxnet.metric.CrossEntropy) and [`NegativeLogLikelihood`](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/api/python/metric/metric.html#mxnet.metric.NegativeLogLikelihood) which have the same definition and very similar implementation. Both have the same core code for calculating metric value:

`self.sum_metric += (-numpy.log(prob + self.eps)).sum()`

If they are essentially the same metrics what is the purpose of maintaining both functions in the library? Which metric is preferred for binary and multi-class classification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually not much difference between these things not only in MXNet, but overall. Read this Quora for more intuition: https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-differences-between-maximum-likelihood-and-cross-entropy-as-a-loss-function

As for what is used for multi-class classification in MXNet, then in majority of examples I have seen people use [SoftmaxCrossEntropyLoss](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/api/python/gluon/loss.html?highlight=softmaxce#mxnet.gluon.loss.SoftmaxCrossEntropyLoss). See an example here: https://gluon.mxnet.io/chapter02_supervised-learning/softmax-regression-gluon.html

Comment: This is weird, if they are identical the source code should explicitly states that 'one is a synonym of the other' and has 1 shared implementation, otherwise it violates the DRY principle